# How to start a row numbers from specific row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with an `ARR` column storing various values. I have to generate row number when my `ARR` column has value 4.

My table

```
Sno   Data   ARR
----------------
 1    AAA     0
 2    AAA     1
 3    AAA     1
 4    AAA     2
 5    AAA     3
 6    AAA     4
 7    AAA     5
 8    AAA     5
 9    AAA     6
10    AAA     4
11    AAA     5
12    AAA     6
```

Required result:

```
Sno   Data   ARR   RowNumber
----------------------------
 1    AAA     0       0
 2    AAA     1       0 
 3    AAA     1       0
 4    AAA     2       0
 5    AAA     3       0
 6    AAA     4       1
 7    AAA     5       2
 8    AAA     5       3
 9    AAA     6       4
10    AAA     4       1
11    AAA     5       2
12    AAA     6       3
```

Here at `Sno=10` (value 4 in `ARR`), the `rownumber` starts again at 1.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want:

```
select t.sno, t.data, t.arr,
       (case when grp >= 1
             then row_number() over (partition by grp order by sno)
             else 0
        end) as rownumber
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when arr = 4 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by sno) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```